# Two different <rich:Panel> changing there position when kept in a single panelGrid

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have two rich:panel(id="pn2" and id="pn3" in given code) in a single h:panelGrid . I have positioned both panels one after another in a Single row .

I have following two problems :

1. As both of these panel are changing height depending on the situation, so when one panel changes  height, second panel is moving up or down from its current position .
2. Why I have to give columns="4" inside the h:PanelGrid for achieving the desired position(Both panels in a single row and one after another)? I have only two panels inside the panelGrid . So, this does not seem to be logical .

   Following is the code:

   ```
                  < h:panelGrid columns="4">

                       <!--This is for setting up the Accounts for customers-->                    
                       <rich:panel id="pn2" rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentItem}" header="Add Account" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 545px; margin-left: -7px">

                           <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                               <a4j:commandButton value="Add New" action="#{adminBean.addAccountAction}" render="pn2" />
                               <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 70px"></a4j:commandButton>
                           </h:panelGrid>

                           <rich:dataScroller for="setacct" style="margin-top: 17px"></rich:dataScroller>
                           <rich:dataTable id="setacct" value="#{adminBean.accountList}" binding="#{adminBean.addAccountTable}" var="acct" rows="10" style="width: 430px; max-height: 10px;">

                               <rich:column id="c1">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Account Type" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder; "/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:inputText value="acct.acctType"></h:inputText>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="c2">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Branch" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:inputText value="acct.branch"></h:inputText>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="c3">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Account Start Date" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <rich:calendar id="calendar" value="acct.acctStartDate"/>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="c4">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <a4j:commandLink value="select"  render="pn3"/>
                               </rich:column>

                           </rich:dataTable>

                       </rich:panel>

                       <!--This is for issuing credit cards for customers-->
                       <rich:panel id="pn3" rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentItem}" header="Add Cards" style="margin-top: 10px; width: 620px; margin-left: 30px">

                           <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                               <a4j:commandButton value="Add New" action="#{adminBean.addCardAction}" render="pn3" style="width: 70px"></a4j:commandButton>
                               <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 70px"></a4j:commandButton>
                           </h:panelGrid>

                           <rich:dataScroller for="setcard" style="margin-top: 17px"></rich:dataScroller>
                           <rich:dataTable id="setcard" value="#{adminBean.cardsList}" binding="#{adminBean.addCardTable}" var="car" rows="10" style="width: 430px; max-height: 10px;">

                               <rich:column id="cl1">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="Card Type" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder; "/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:inputText value="#{car.type}"></h:inputText>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="cl2">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="VALID FROM" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <rich:calendar value="#{car.validFrom}" id="cal2"/>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="cl3">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="EXPIRY ON" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <rich:calendar value="#{car.expiryOn}" id="cal3"/>
                               </rich:column>

                               <rich:column id="cl4">
                                   <f:facet name="header">
                                       <h:outputText value="AUTO ALERT" style="font-size: smaller; font-weight: bolder;"/>
                                   </f:facet>
                                   <h:inputText value="#{car.autoMsg}"></h:inputText>
                               </rich:column>

                           </rich:dataTable>

                       </rich:panel>
                   </h:panelGrid>
   ```

Can anybody tell that what is the reason behind changing position of both panels ? Note : here Height of both the panels are dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the problem1, h:panelGrid just a layout but nothing about the height.
For the height you'll need to use css to control that.

For problem2, try to remove those

```
<!--This is for setting up the Accounts for customers-->
```

in your code.